# Actions on Google smart home app test fail

Tags: actions-on-google

I am developing a smart home app for google home to control smart devices.
I use gactions to push my app for testing:

```
gactions test --action_package action.json --project <project-name>
```

Everything works fine until today, the test command returns error:

```
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "device_control" at 'preview_
action_package.action_package.actions[0]': Cannot find field.
Field Violations:
#  Field                                             Description
1  preview_action_package.action_package.actions[0]  Invalid JSON payload receiv
ed. Unknown name "device_control" at 'preview_action_package.action_package.acti
ons[0]': Cannot find field.
2017/05/26 09:39:10 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

here is my action.json, it's not changed since created:

```
{
    "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
    "conversations": {
      "automation": {
        "name": "automation",
        "url": "<my web endpoint>"
      }
    }
}
```

There is no device_control in my action.json.
After some try, it seems the parser treat 'C' as '_c'.

Is this an issue on Google's end?

Comment: Hi, just want to ask if you were able to test your smart home app successfully either on the simulator or on google assistant?

Comment: Yes, I can test my smart home app on Google Home. Basically, smart home app can't be tested on the simulator because you can't do account linking on the simulator.

Comment: Do you by any chance, know the cause that test version of smart home app is not appearing under home controls?

Comment: If you did all the steps for creating and testing smart home app, and the gactions test command also succeeded. Then I suggest you contact AoG support channel. They told me somebody encounter this issue, but the cause varies by case. So maybe you should contact AoG support directly and let them assist you to find the cause.

Comment: Thank you :) I contacted them already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove that:

"deviceControl": {
 },

in your action package, then it will work.

I just verified this way works.

Answer (score 2):

Google's JSON handling often treats camelCaseNaming and underscore_naming as equivalent. In this case, `deviceControl` and `device_control` are referencing the same thing.

The current (as of 18 May 2017) specification for an [Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Action) in the action package does not include `deviceControl` as a valid field. The [only reference](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#create_a_developer_project_and_action_package) I can find to `deviceControl` is in descriptive documentation about the action package, but it is similarly left blank and not described there.

You can probably safely remove this entry.

Comment: It seems that smart home app requires this entry. When I remove this entry from action.json, the error message shows "Action with built-in namespace 'actions.devices' must specify DeviceControl in the config".

Comment: Try again. It sounds like they heard our reports and have removed the check for this field at all.